# Get an offset of a cell that contains a string in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have a long list of amounts and its totals in the same column, I want to extract the totals seperately. I've tried index, match vtable etc. I just cant seem to be able to make this work.

3700
240
931

above is what i need.

The following works but only for the first entry.

=OFFSET(Sheet16!B1, INDEX( MATCH("Total",Sheet16!B:B,0)),0)

I would get 3700 with this. But i need the whole list.

Comment: You may try `WRAPCOLS/WRAPROWS` or `FILTER()` with `SCAN()` function. Share a sample gs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=filter(A2:A21,A1:A20="TOTAL")
```

[image]

Comment: I cant believe it was this simple, thank you so much